# How change value of fields marked with the annotation by the annotation processing

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

How to set the value of the variable and then after the calculation read it using annotation processing? I know how to do this with reflection, but I need to use annotation processing mechanism. Is it possible? Do I have to change something in the annotation?

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Bind {

}

public class Model1 {
@Bind private int LL;
@Bind private  double[] twKI;
@Bind private  double[] twKS;
@Bind private  double[] twINW;
@Bind private  double[] twEKS;
@Bind private  double[] twIMP;
@Bind private double[] KI;
@Bind private double[] KS;
@Bind private double[] INW;
@Bind private double[] EKS;
@Bind private double[] IMP;
@Bind private double[] PKB;

 public Model1() {}

 public void run() {
 PKB = new double[LL];
 PKB[0] = KI[0] + KS[0] + INW[0] + EKS[0] - IMP[0];
 for (int t=1; t < LL; t++) {
  KI[t] = twKI[t]* KI[t-1];
  KS[t] = twKS[t]* KS[t-1];
  INW[t] = twINW[t]* INW[t-1];
  EKS[t] = twEKS[t]* EKS[t-1];
  IMP[t] = twIMP[t]* IMP[t-1];
  PKB[t] = KI[t] + KS[t] + INW[t] + EKS[t] - IMP[t];
  }
 }
}


 /* Part of the code in which I set the values */
 public class Controller{
 ...
 private Class class1;
 private Object modelName;

 class1 = Class.forName("zad1.models."+model);
 modelName = class1.newInstance();
 Field fieldtkWI  = class1.getDeclaredField("twKI");
 fieldtkWI.setAccessible(true);
 fieldtkWI.set(modelName, twKI);
 }
```

EDIT: 
This annotation is to allow:

- assigning value to the output variable of the model before performing calculations,
- downloading the values of variables calculated in the model (after calculations have been carried out).

Comment: Reflection *is* a kind of annotation processing mechanism

Comment: It is also about some way to refer to this annotation because if you delete it, the code I wrote will continue to work the same way without it.